# php - preg-replace not working

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$file = 'test.php';
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="test">
  <p>It test</p>
  <form class="FormTest">
    <input type="text" name="rel">
  </form>
  <form class="FormTest2">
    <input type="text" name="rel">
  </form>
</div>
```

**in next step we get content index.php and remove `form`:**

```
ob_start(); // start output buffer
include $file;
$template = ob_get_contents(); // get contents of buffer
ob_end_clean();
$template = preg_replace('/<form.*?class="FormTest".*?>.*?<\/form>/',
'', $template );
```

But it not work and `form.FormTest` not remove...

Tell me please where problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ob_start(); // start output buffer
include $file;
$template = ob_get_contents(); // get contents of buffer
$template = preg_replace('/<form.*?class="FormTest".*?>.*?<\/form>/',
'', $template );
ob_end_clean();
```

Just `ob_end_clean();` should be at the end

Alternatively you can do this as well

`ob_get_clean()` essentially executes both `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`

```
ob_start(); // start output buffer
include $file;
$template = ob_get_clean();
$template = preg_replace('/<form.*?class="FormTest".*?>.*?<\/form>/','', $template );
echo $template ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the multiline modifier with /m in your regex expression:

```
$template = preg_replace('/<form.*?class="FormTest".*?>.*?<\/form>/m', '', $template );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your preg_replace code to the following:

```
$template = preg_replace('/<form.*?class="FormTest.*?form>/s','', $template );
```

It worked for me when placing your HTML into $template as a String.

Answer (score 0):

Your dots need to also match newline, so add s-modifier

```
$template = preg_replace('/<form.*?class="FormTest".*?>.*?<\/form>/s', '', $template );
```

Answer (score -1):

the following code should work

```
$template = 'this is just a test<form class="FormTest">form will be removed</form>...';
$template = preg_replace('/<form.*?class="FormTest".*?>.*?<\/form>/', '', $template);

echo $template;
```